# How to upgrade Magento 2.1.2 to 2.1.4 in Local Machine & Server side?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

How to upgrade Magento 2.1.2 to 2.1.4 in Local & Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Log in to your Magento server as, or switch to, the Magento file system owner.
2. Change to the directory in which you installed the Magento software.
3. Enter the following commands in the order shown:

> ```
> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.4 --no-update
> composer update
> ```

4. If prompted, enter your authentication keys.
5. Manually clear var subdirectories:

> ```
> rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
> rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
> rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/generation/*
> ```

6/ Update the database schema and data:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

7/ Restart Varnish if you use it for page caching.

`service varnish restart`

8/ Access your storefront.

The following error might display:

`We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.``

If so, perform the following tasks:

Reset file system ownership and permissions as a user with root privileges.
Clear the following directories and try again:

`<your Magento install dir>/var/cache 
<your Magento install dir>/var/page_cache 
<your Magento install dir>/var/generation`

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: In Local machine composer update command not work..

Comment: What error is appearing when you run `composer update` in your local machine?

Comment: bash: composer: command not found.

Comment: Run `which composer` to know your complete path to composer

Comment: No composer found.how to setup?? i already run composer install command but same error.

Comment: Get composer on Google https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: Download manually but which folder in set?

Comment: Read instructions please https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: thnx..working..

Comment: Cool, you welcome!